# Data parsing With Soap Engine in Swift

Tags: swift, soap

in swift 2.0 using **SOAP Engine** to parse data.

having a problem while taking data into an NSArray.

```
  soap.requestURL("URL",
        soapAction: "ActionURL",
        completeWithDictionary: { (statusCode : Int, dict : [NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void in

            var result:Dictionary = dict as Dictionary
            NSLog("%@", result)
```

From ***NSLog*** the data which i receive is :

```
{
    Results =     {
        Result =         (
                        {
                ILCE = "ALA";
                KOD = 21894;
                MAHALLE = "ATATURK";
                MAHALLEKOD = 57;
                YOL = "ATATURK";
            },
                        {
                ILCE = "DEN";
                KOD = 21894;
                MAHALLE = "KAZIM D\U0130R\U0130K";
                MAHALLEKOD = 257;
                YOL = "ATAT\U00dcRK";
            },
                        {
                ILCE = "AL\U0130A\U011eA";
                KOD = 21894;
                MAHALLE = "K\U00dcLT\U00dcR";
                MAHALLEKOD = 517;
                YOL = "ATAT\U00dcRK";
            },
```

I only want to get the ***Result*** instead of ***Results*** into the NSArray. Here is what i do :

```
                let sonuclar = result["Results"]

          ->    let aramalar: NSArray = sonuclar as! NSArray
                print(aramalar)

                self.aramalar = aramalar
                self.table.reloadData()

            }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in

                NSLog("%@", error)
        }
```

But at this point on "aramalar" i m reciving an error such

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1038ced38) to 'NSArray' (0x1038ce900).

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer.

***Here what have to do :***

```
let sonuclar = dict["Results"]!["Result"]
```

"Results" is a dictionary with one key named "Result", this key named "Result" is a array of dictionary.